# Drag drop clone and resize using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have some jquery code that i want to able to drag, drop, clone and resize. I can drag and drop and resize at the first attempt. After which i drag the cloned item around the container, it is not able to resize anymore. Any idea why?

my HTML,css and jquery from dragndrop.js as below

```
.col{
    float:left;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

#col1{
    width:200px;
    height:500px;
    border:1px solid black;

}

.drag{
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid black;
    height:40px;
    position:relative;
    background-color:red;
}

#droppable{
    width:500px;
    height :500px;
    border:1px solid black;
    }

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dragndrop.css" />
        <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
           google.load("jquery", "1.6.3");
           google.load("jqueryui", "1.8.16");
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
        <script src="dragndrop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div class = "col" id="col1">
                <div id="drag1" class="drag">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col" id ="droppable">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

$(document).ready(function () {

    var x = null;

    //Make element draggable
    $(".drag").draggable({
        helper: 'clone',
        cursor: 'move',
        tolerance: 'fit'
    });

    $("#droppable").droppable({

        drop: function(e, ui) {

            x = ui.helper.clone();
                  x.draggable({
                helper: 'original',
                containment: '#droppable',
                tolerance: 'fit'
            });
            x.resizable({
                maxHeight: 40,
                minHeight:40,
                minWidth:50
            });
            x.appendTo('#droppable');
            ui.helper.remove();
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: You reference a script file dragndrop.js - can you provide that script as well?

Comment: oh the dragndrop.js is the jquery code i posted above. Sorry that i did not clarify clearly about it

Comment: you may also want to post the relevant portions of the CSS

Comment: yup. sorry about it. css added as well.

Comment: I created a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CVfMp/3/. you mentioned that it could resize, but I am unable to get anything to resize.

Comment: Could you perhaps try a resizing one on your own jsfiddle and share that

Comment: oh I tried as well, the resizing doesnt work, so i added the scripts in html instead of choosing the options on the left. the jsfiddle link is http://jsfiddle.net/ezzxX/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that you were cloning the div that was already on the droppable surface.

I added check (may need to be updated) to see if the id was set (when they were cloned the id was set to "") and if it was blank then clone and add to droppable surface, otherwise, leave it alone, it's already droppable.

```
        $("#droppable").droppable({

            drop: function (e, ui) {

                if ($(ui.draggable)[0].id != "") {
                    x = ui.helper.clone();
                ui.helper.remove();
                x.draggable({
                    helper: 'original',
                    containment: '#droppable',
                    tolerance: 'fit'
                });
                x.resizable({
                    maxHeight: 40,
                    minHeight: 40,
                    minWidth: 50
                });
                x.appendTo('#droppable');
            }

            }
        });
```

See full demonstration here http://jsfiddle.net/ezzxX/2/